# Open set in such a set w.r.t weak topology

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\mathcal X,\mathcal F)$ be a measurable space and $\mathcal P$ the set of probability measures  on this space. With weak convergence (i.e., $P_n\to P$ weakly if and only if $\mathbb E_{P_n}(f)\to\mathbb E_P(f)$ for every bounded continuous functions $f:\mathcal X\to\mathbb R$), a basis of the corresponding weak topology induced by this weak convergence is a collection of the following sets:
$$U(P,\alpha)=\left\{Q:\left|\int f_idP-\int f_idQ\right|<\alpha,i=1,\ldots,n\right\}$$
for some $P\in\mathcal P$, $f_i$ bounded continuous functions, $n$ is finite, and $\alpha>0$. Then there exists a finite measurable partition $A_1,\ldots,A_m$ of $\mathcal X$ and $\beta>0$ such that
\begin{align}
\tilde{U}(P,\beta)=\{Q:|P(A_j)-Q(A_j)|<\beta\}\subset{U}(P,\alpha).
\end{align}

My questions are:

1. is $\tilde{U}(P,\epsilon)$ also open?
2. if not, is there an open set, say $U'(P, \alpha')$, that is contained in $\tilde{U}(P,\beta)$? or under what conditions there exists such a $U'(P, \alpha')$? (might have different bounded continuous functions)

Can you help me with these question? or please see my thinking below.

---

Let me first prove the existence of such $\tilde{U}(P,\beta)\subset U(P,\alpha).$

Since $f_i$ is bounded continuous, then there exists a simple function $\tilde f_i$ such that $\|f_i-\tilde f_i\|_{\infty} <\frac{\alpha}{3}$. Then if $|\int \tilde{f}_idP - \int \tilde{f}_idQ|<\frac{\alpha}{3}$, we have 
\begin{align}
&\left|\int f_idP-\int f_idQ\right|\\
=~&\left|\int f_idP-\int \tilde f_idP+\int \tilde f_idP-\int \tilde f_idQ+\int \tilde f_idQ-\int f_idQ\right|\\
<~&\alpha.
\end{align}
We can then define a finite partition according to these simple functions, as $f_i$'s are bounded. By choosing a small enough $\beta$, $|P(A_j)-Q(A_j)|<\beta$ for all $i$ implies $|\int \tilde f_idP-\int \tilde f_idQ|<\frac{\alpha}{3}$.

---

I have no idea about question 1, so I go to question 2, thinking to construct some bounded continuous functions to build a new open set.

a). for each measurable set $A_i$, find two continuous functions $\bar{f_i}$ and $\underline{f_i}$, such that 
$$\bar{f_i}(x)\geq I_{A_i}(x)\geq \underline{f_i}(x),~\text{for every $x\in\mathcal X$},$$
$$\int \bar{f_i} dP- \int \underline{f_i}dP<\frac{\beta}{2},$$
where $I_{A_i}(\cdot)$ is the indicator function.

b). For any probability measure $Q$, we have $$\int\underline{f_i}dQ\leq Q(A_i)\leq\int\bar{f_i}dQ.$$ Thus, if $|\int\bar{f_i}dP - \int\underline{f_i}dQ|<\beta$ and $|\int\underline{f_i}dP - \int\bar{f_i}dQ|<\beta$, we must have $|P(A_i)-Q(A_i)|<\beta$. We also have
\begin{align}
&\left|\int\underline{f_i}dP - \int\bar{f_i}dQ\right|\\
=~&\left|\int\underline{f_i}dP-\int\bar{f_i}dP+\int\bar{f_i}dP-\int\bar{f_i}dQ \right|\\
\leq~&\left|\int\underline{f_i}dP-\int\bar{f_i}dP\right|+\left|\int\bar{f_i}dP-\int\bar{f_i}dQ \right|
\end{align}
Similarly, we have $$\left|\int\bar{f_i}dP - \int\underline{f_i}dQ\right|\leq\left|\int\bar{f_i}dP-\int\underline{f_i}dP\right|+\left|\int\underline{f_i}dP-\underline{f_i}dQ \right|$$

As such, adding the following constraints $$\left|\int\underline{f_i}dP-\underline{f_i}dQ \right|<\frac{\beta}{2}, \left|\int\bar{f_i}dP-\bar{f_i}dQ \right|<\frac{\beta}{2}$$
will construct a new open set that is contained in $\tilde{U}(P,\beta)$.

It seems that a) is not always true. When $\mathcal X=\mathbb R$, consider $P= \frac{1}{2}I_{[0,1]} + \frac{1}{2}I_{\{3\}}$. For a measurable set $A=[2,3)$, no such $\bar{f_i}$ and $\underline{f_i}$ exist for each $\beta>0$. I think it possible to place some constraints on the partition $A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_m$ for the simple functions $\tilde f_i$, but I got no formal proof/reference to it. Can you advise me how to make this work? Thanks!!~

Comment: It seems that if we can let $P(int A_i) = P(cl A_i)$, then we can find such $\bar{f_i}$ and $\underline{f_i}$ always exist. But I am wondering: 1) is this true for more than $\mathcal X=\mathbb R$? 2) can we always find such a partition of $A_i'$ 's such that $P(int A_i) = P(cl A_i)$ for each $i$? Thanks.

Comment: Just find that $P(intA_i)=P(clA_i)$ means $A_i$ is a continuity set. So the question becomes, if there always exists a finite partition $A_i$'s of $\mathcal X$ such that each $A_i$ is $P$-continuity? Also, assume that $\mathcal X$ is Polish space if necessary.

Comment: Is $f_i$ fixed? That is, does every open set depend on the same $f_i$ or can two different sets be open with respect to two different lots of $f_i$?

Comment: @FGJones Can be different. Any finitely many bounded continuous functions and positive $\alpha$ leads to an open set, and the collection of all of them form a basis of the weak topology.

Comment: You didn't completely explain the context you have in mind.  You began by just assuming a measurable space, but suddenly the space got a topology.

Comment: Sorry that was cryptic.  I mean suddenly you began talking about continuous functions on $\mathcal X$.

Comment: @fredgoodman sorry for this. I was thinking that it was kind of a convention to say 'weak topology' on the space of all probability measures. The weak topology is induced from weak convergence, i.e., a sequence of probability measures $P_n\to P$ weakly iff. $\mathbb E_{P_n}(f(x))\to\mathbb E_P(f(x))$ for every bounded continuous functions $f:\mathcal X\to\mathbb R$. I will also add this in the problem part. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true, let $X=[-1,1]$ and consider $P = \delta_0$. Let $f_1,...,f_n$ be continuous on $X$. Note that $U_{\{f_1,..,f_n\}}(P,\epsilon)=\bigcap_i U_{f_i}(P,\epsilon)$.

You can do a continuity argument to find non-singular measures $Q=\frac1h \chi_{[-h,h]}$ so that for any fixed $f$ you have $Q\in U_f(P,\epsilon)$. So any weak-open set around $f$ contains non-singular measures. On the other hand let $A=\{0\}$, then
$$\tilde U_A (P,\epsilon) = \{Q\mid |1-Q(\{0\})|<\epsilon\}$$
contains *only* measures that are singular (provided $\epsilon<1$), thus this cannot be an open neighbourhood of $P$.

If you restrict your $A_i$ to be open the statement should be true (if your measure space has the Borel sigma algebra), if necessary add in $X$ to be locally compact and probability measures to be regular.

Comment: Great. I will continue the rest. I also get from Dembo and Zeitouni's book ('Large Deviations Techniques and Applications') that the collections of such $\tilde{U}(P,\epsilon)$ (now not necessarily defined by a subset of an open set in weak topology) form a basis of the $\tau$-topology on $\mathcal P$, which is a stronger topology.

Comment: Perhaps another question, while continuing, if $\Gamma\subset\mathcal P$, and let $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ be a finite measurable partition, is $\{P(A_1), P(A_2),\ldots,P(A_n):P\in cl\Gamma\}$ closed in $\mathbb R^n$? Assume Borel Sigma algebra, and if necessary other assumptions on the alphabet $\mathcal X$, too.

Comment: I am kind of new to the measure theory part. Besides the additional question, can you also recommend some materials on probability measures and the (weak) topology? Thanks!

Comment: I like to use Simon & Reed as a reference for functional analysis. Other standard works are Rudin and Conway. I don't know any particular book that does measure theory nicely. I'm not sure about your second question, but have also not really thought about it. You way want to ask it as a separate question.

Comment: Thanks! Will go through these materials first and try the question myself.